Iterate over all matches in a file for a regex pattern in zsh
What is the tersest way to efficiently iterate over all matches in a file for a regex pattern in zsh using a completely zsh-native method, instead of using external commands like grep?
Is there any way to use process substitution to read the file into a variable, then use some bash syntax / expansion / builtin / whatever either to iterate over matches or to save the matches into an array over which to iterate. The simplest way I know to do this is to loop using the =~ conditional and the match variable to obtain one match per iteration, and to truncate the value to remove the most recent match on each iteration. That seems overly verbose, and that would presumably copy the remaining text of the value on each iteration. It would presumably be more performant (but also more verbose) to specify a start index for each regex match, progressing the start index past the most recent match on each iteration instead of truncating the value, but I don't know if that's possible in zsh. A dedicated syntax to iterate over all regex matches from the variable (or from the file) or to output an array containing all matches from the variable (or from the file) would be nicer, if either exists.
I could iterate over an array created from a command substitution of a grep (or similar external command) of the file, but I'd prefer to not use any external commands.

Just being curious: Is this a programming homework problem? In a realistic situation, I don't see much benefit for not using grep here. You can of course loop over the lines of your file explicitly, but then you have to take care to get all matches of each line. Why reinventing the wheel, if grep is doing what you want? The overhead is neglegible, since it is only one single child process for the whole file. If speed would be really a question, you would do this neither with grep nor with zsh, but perhaps entirely in i.e. Perl or Ruby or Rust.

No, it's not homework. I've just recently learned about various useful zsh features that I could have been using for years (not that I do much zsh scripting, but I could use the features in some manually typed commands), so I just want to learn more about the capabilities of zsh to see what I'm missing out on…

Well, zsh allows you to loop over all lines in a file, and allows you to do a regex match on a string. Of course you can put together out of this a program which is doing what you want, but to get all matches in a line with just internal commands requires some efforts. There is no "dedicated syntax" here; you have to program it yourself. zsh's main strength is not string processing, so don't expect too much comfort here.

Thanks for the info. I'd probably just use grep, then, if zsh doesn't have a convenient syntax for doing this.

Just one recommendation from my personal experience: While zsh has very cute features for scripting, in particular when dealing with file names, it still is first of all a language for "shell scripting", which means that it does not have very elegant data types. String manipulations are still restricted, and if you do a lot of array manipulation, you will be surprised how slow things can be, compared to other languages.  Just because you can do something in zsh, does not mean that it will make you happy doing it.

arr=(${(f)"$(<file.txt)"});arr=(${(M)arr:#*word*}). This uses zsh glob patterns instead of EREs; there's a great list of what's available here. Can be made even terser: arr=(${(M)${(f)"$(<file.txt)"}:#*word*}).

If I understand you correctly: You have a file, and you have a regex pattern, and you want to iterate over all matches of the regex, and do this with zsh.
Assumption:

Your regex is stored in variable re.
Your filename is stored in variable file.

for match in $(grep -o $re $file)
do
  : match contains the matched part of the regular expression
done

Note that this assumes that re is a simple regular expression. Use -E if it is an extended regex, or -P if it is a perl-re.

Yes, but is there any way to do it without using an external command like grep?

I reworded my question to show that I know how to do it with grep , but that I'd prefer to not use any external commands.

@XDR: Since the purpose of Stackoverflow is to accumulate over time a "database" of problems and their solutions, it is discouraged to change your questions in a way to invalidate an answer. Instead it is better to ask a new question.

FYI, I did not downvote the answer. Don't want you to think I did that.
